# Image of closed unit ball is not closed

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

> Define $T\colon c_0\rightarrow\ell^1$ by setting $$T(x)=\left(\frac{x_n}{n^2}\right),\quad \text{for each}\  x=(x_n)\in c_0.$$ Show that $T\in\mathcal{B}(c_0,\ell^1)$. If $B$ is the closed unit ball in $c_0$, show that $T(B)$ is not closed in $\ell^1$.

In the first part I argue in the following way: For each $x\in c_0$, we have that \begin{eqnarray}\|T(x)\|_1&=&\left\|\left(x_1,\frac{x_2}{2^2},...,\frac{x_n}{n^2},...\right)\right\|_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{x_n}{n^2}\right|\\
&\leqslant&\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sup_{n\in\Bbb{N}}|x_n|}{n^2}=\|x\|_\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2},
\end{eqnarray}
where the last term on expression is finite, since $x\in c_0$ and the other factor is a $p$-series with $p=2$. Therefore $T$ is bounded.

But I have no idea how to procede in the second part (show that $T(B)$ is not closed in $\ell^1$, where $B$ is the closed unit ball in $c_0$).

Comment: Find an $x \in \overline{T(B)}\setminus T(B)$. There is a candidate that sticks out.

Comment: Taking elements of $B$, I think the images have module tending to $0$, but not can be $0$, am I right?

Comment: What does this exercice tend to show ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the point $y=(1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},...,\frac{1}{n^2},...)$ and $x_n \in c_0$ such that
$$x_1=(1,0,0........)$$  $$x_2=(1,1,0,0.....)$$ $$x_3=(1,1,1,0,..)$$ e.t.c. Then $x_n \in B, \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$ and $T(x_n) \to y$ thus $y \in \overline{T(B)}$

But if existed $z=(z_k) \in B$ such that $T(z)=y$ then we would have that $z_k=1,\forall k \in \Bbb{N} \Longrightarrow z \notin c_0$ which is a contradiction.