# Question in the definition of Compact Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, examples-counterexamples, compact-operators

One of the definitions of compact operators is the following.

**Definition**: Let X and Y be two Banach spaces. An operator $T : X \rightarrow Y$ is compact if for every bounded set $ \subset X$
and every sequence $(x_i) \subset M$, the sequence $(Tx_i)$ contains a convergent subsequence.

**Edit**:

Another definition for compact operator is: $T$ maps bounded sets $M$ to relatively compact sets, $TM$, in the codomain.

Notice that this is weaker than mapping bounded sets to compact sets since we do not have the requirement that $TM$ is compact because it is possible that $TM$ is not closed.

**Problem**: I am trying to find a bounded set whose image under a compact operator is not closed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I mean the following: Can we find a compact operator such that for any bounded $M \subset X$ we have $(x_n) \subset M$ and $(Tx_n)$ contains a convergent subsequence $(Tx_{n_k}) \in Y \setminus TM$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks, edited.

Comment: Since the $x_n$'s are in $M$, the $Tx_n$'s (in particular the $Tx_{n_k}$'s) are in $TM.$ So your question, as reformulated in your comment, makes no sense.

Comment: @AnneBauval What do you mean? Why can't the subsequence converge to a point outside of M? For instance, take any open interval, then we can, in some way, build an operator $T$, so that $(Tx_n)$ converges outside of $TM$?

Comment: My first guess for what you meant by «if the convergence of the subsequences must be in TM» was indeed «if the *limit* of the subsequences must be in TM» and I answered (now deleted): TM is not necessarily closed. But then in your comment, you said you meant something else, namely $(Tx_{n_k}) \in Y \setminus TM$. *This* question makes no sense;

Comment: @AnneBauval May I ask for an example of M bounded and TM not closed?

Comment: See the link given by Mariano in his comment above, 11 mins ago

Comment: @AnneBauval I don't see the relation of $TX$ not being closed with the implication that there exists a bounded set $M \subset X$ such that $TM$ is not closed.

Comment: You are right. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3483978) is a better link for that subsidiary question. But can you please edit your post to clarify your main question? (i.e. answer Mariano's 1st comment)

Comment: This answers your question: [Image of closed unit ball is not closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3483978/image-of-closed-unit-ball-is-not-closed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f : (c_{0}, \|\cdot\|_\infty) \to \Bbb{C}$ be the linear functional
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{2^n}, \qquad \text{ for all }x = (x_n)_n \in c_0.$$
Then $f$ is clearly compact since it has finite rank. However, the image of the open unit ball in $c_0$ is the open unit ball in $\Bbb{C}$ which is not a closed set in $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: This answer  is a duplicate of the link given in comment 11 hours before. (At that time I could not vote to close as a duplicate because the question was still unclear. But it was edited just before your answer.)

Comment: @AnneBauval I'm sorry, I didn't see the link as I didn't read the comments carefully since the question changed a few minutes before I posted my answer. Anyway, now that the deed is done, I wouldn't say that they are exactly the same because this one is a linear functional and hence perhaps a bit simpler to think of and to prove the required properties.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. My turn to not have read carefully.